# Let $G$ be connected graph $r−$regular, show that if $G$ complement is connected but is not Hamiltonian. Then $G$ is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I've been stuck in this homewoork problem, and I've already asked my teacher and he told me that I have the idea by contradiction using Ore's Theorem and by watching $r$.
But I got some issues beacause for example. Assuming that $G$ is not Hamiltonian then for every non-adyacents vertexs $u$ and $v$ then $d(u) + d(v) < n$.
Notice that $d(u) = d(v)$.

But, for example when you have a $2-$regular Graph on $6$ vertexs then $d(u) + d(v) = 4$b
and $4 \geq 6$, not true. But this Graph still Hamiltonian.

So I'm stuck here.
I'm trying by cases when $|V(G)|$ is odd and when is even.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $G$ is $r$ regular, then it's complement is $n-1-r$ regular,

If neither $G$ or $\overline{G}$ is Hamiltonian, then by Ore Theorem
$$r+r \leq n-1 \\
(n-1-r)+(n-1-r) \leq n-1$$

Deduce from here that $r=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Then $n$ needs to be odd, and hence, by Handshaking Lemma of the form $4k+1$.

This solves the problem unless $n=4k+1$ and $r=2k$.

The last case follows from  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470324/difficulty-in-proof-of-nash-williams-theorem-on-hamilton-cycles-in-regular-graph)

Comment: Yes, I was on my way to that but I was using r +r < n and (n-r-1) + (n-r-1) < n

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey N.S but for example the 6-regular graph with 10 vertexs is hamiltonian, but its complement is connected and not hamiltonian ):

Comment: And 10 is even :/

Comment: @DavidHernándezUriostegui I do not get your point. I am claiming that when $n \neq 4k+1$ then EITHER $G$ OR its complement is Hamiltonian. Your example does NOT contradict this.

Comment: @DavidHernándezUriostegui Your problem says that $\bar{G}$ is not Hamiltonian. Then, by the above $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: now i get it, I didn't understand the Nash's Williams Theorem, but now I fanally understand it.

Comment: so if n = 4k+1 and  r = 2k we get a contradiction because we're assuming that G is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DavidHernándezUriostegui Or you apply that result to $\bar{G}$.